# Move command lost file

Tags: linux

Did this once before but managed to find the file, however this time it seems to be gone or perhaps invisible?
`mv foo.mpg /foo`

Comment: oops I found it sorry, it is in / and been renamed as the folder name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `/foo` is an existing directory, the file should be in that directory. Otherwise your file `foo.mpg` just got moved to `/` and renamed to `foo` and should be in `/`. (If you did not see any error message on this command, that is. Normally, you should not be able to write to `/`.)

Comment: yes thanks I worked it out , that's exactly what happened.